# QGIS composer export to grayscale

Tags: qgis

Is there a possibility to create output (export) pdf (or svg) in grayscale using Print Composer in QGIS without changing color schemes in main map window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In print composer you can preview in greyscale View > Preview > Simulated Photocopy.

Then, in Gimp (or image editor of you preference), you can usually match the simulated results by desaturating the image. In Gimp: Colors > Desaturate. If this doesn't give you the desired result, you can try [other greyscaling methods](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Color2BW/).

You can get [Gimp here](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/).

Comment: It means there is no way to do it directly, right? Anyway, thank you for providing a simple (and free) workaround.

Comment: No direct way. The source for [qgiscomposer.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/1b4bd47076103e931e642c9c2b6a363f14b20a45/src/app/composer/qgscomposer.cpp) could be extended at the print dialogue to allow greyscale printing - using qt's [qprint::ColourMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#ColorMode-enum). An image might be able to be converted using a similar approach to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949569/convert-a-qimage-to-grayscale). SVG - not sure.